# Как вывести результат выполнения программы на R через Python?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

Есть программа, написанная на R, и результат выполнения этой программы необходимо вывести через Python. Сначала я попробовала следующий вариант:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call ("C:\py\test.R", shell=True)
```

Однако возвращается 1 (по всей видимости, то, что код выполнен успешно), и это не то, что мне нужно. Также я пробовала установить модуль rpy2, но с ним возникли ошибки при установке.
Затем я попробовала следующую конструкцию:

```
import subprocess 
command = ("C:\R400\bin\Rscript.exe " "--vanilla C:\py\test.R") 
subprocess.Popen(command)
variable_name = subprocess.check_output(command)
print(variable_name)
```

Однако выполнение данного кода в Jupyter Notebook и IDLE Python 3.8 (64 бит) на Windows 10 приводит к ошибке:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

В чём может быть причина этого? Как исправить? 
Как всё-таки выполнить программу на R через Python в обход использования модуля rpy2?

UPD.
Ещё я пробовала через командную строку.
Создавался файл run.py в папке с файлом test.R со следующим кодом:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['Rscript', 'test.R'], shell=False)
```

Однако `python3 run.py` через командную строку ни к чему не приводил. Не удалось записать результат в специально созданный текстовый файл testout.txt через `python3 run.py > testout.txt`

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `subprocess.call ("C:\py\test.R", shell=True)` на `subprocess.call (r"C:\py\test.R", shell=True)` либо `subprocess.call ("C:\\py\\test.R", shell=True)`

Comment: К сожалению, оба варианта приводят к возврату всё той же единицы ):

Comment: исправил метки: к программе `r` (и к языку `r`) вопрос не имеет ни малейшего отношения. имеет он отношение к программе `python` и операционной системе `ms/windows`.